# How much health do Lieutenants have?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In Batman: Arkham City, there are big brutes that are fought, and the second biggest of them all are Lieutenants. They are one-armed and either wield a sledgehammer or a scythe. Attacking them counts for normal strikes, but with the speed of a beat-down.

How many strikes does it take to take down a Lieutenant?

'Figured that I'd make this question since I made the other one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of strikes, 49 + 1 finishing blow.  If they're alone, they are taken down by 14 strikes + 1 finishing blow.

How many batarangs does it take to take down a Lieutenant? If they're alone, it takes 27 - 2 from x0 combo (the first x2 batarangs don't count for damage).

Once they're on their [magic pixel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CriticalExistenceFailure), they can only be taken down by a strike or directed aerial assault and batarangs no longer build more than a x2 combo against them.